# In the expression '탈코르셋', what is the meaning of '탈'?

Tags: vocabulary

As I understand it, '탈코르셋' is a name given to a current wave of feeling in Korea against objectification of women, unattainable standards of beauty, etc. I assume '코르셋' is the English word 'Corset', but what is '탈'? [Naver dictionary](https://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en&isOnlyViewEE=N&query=%ED%83%88) gives the meanings 'mask' or 'disease', but I guess it's neither of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 탈출 : escape 탈피 : molting 탈의 : taking off clothes

탈권의주의 : not-authoritarianism

2) 배(belly) 에 탈이 나다 : I am in stomach.

(그 일 하는데) 또 탈났어 : When I do the thing, there is a
   problem again

3) 탈춤 : mask dance

Answer (score 6):

탈 is from the 한자 character [脫 (called 벗을 탈)](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/hanja?q=%E8%84%AB&cp_code=0&sound_id=0), meaning to take off, shed, get out of, escape.

We can see it in many words:

- 탈북 (脫北) - "escape North" - escaping from North Korea
- 탈출 (脫出) - escape, running away
- 탈옥 (脫獄) - escape from prison
- 탈의실 (脫衣室) - changing room (literally "take off clothes room")

It is common enough as a prefix (or the first part of a word) that it is somewhat clear that the general meaning of 탈코르셋 is related to 'removing the corset'.  Of course, the way you have explained it gives the fuller meaning of the word.